# unable to run mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have installed mongo-connector in the mongodb server.

I am executing by giving the command

```
mongo-connector -m [remote mongo server IP]:[remote mongo server port] -t [elastic search server IP]:[elastic search server Port]  -d elastic_doc_manager.py
```

I also tried with this since mongo is running in the same server with the default port.

```
mongo-connector -t [elastic search server IP]:[elastic search server Port]  -d elastic_doc_manager.py
```

I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mongo-connector==2.3.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'mongo-connector')()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1037, in main
    conf.parse_args()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/config.py", line 118, in parse_args
    option, dict((k, values.get(k)) for k in option.cli_names))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 820, in apply_doc_managers
    module = import_dm_by_name(dm['docManager'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 810, in import_dm_by_name
    "Could not import %s." % full_name)

**mongo_connector.errors.InvalidConfiguration: Could not import mongo_connector.doc_managers.elastic_doc_manager.py.**
```

NOTE: I am using python2.7
and mongo-connector 2.3

Elastic search server is 2.2

Any suggestions ?

**[edit]**
After applying `Val`'s suggestion:

> 2016-02-29 19:56:59,519 [CRITICAL] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:549 -
>   Exception during collection dump
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py",
>   line 501, in do_dump
>
> upsert_all(dm)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py",
>   line 485, in upsert_all dm.bulk_upsert(docs_to_dump(namespace),
>   mapped_ns, long_ts)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/util.py", line 32, in wrapped
>
> return f(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-2.3.dev0-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic_doc_manager.py", line 190, in bulk_upsert
>
> for ok, resp in responses:
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/helpers/init.py",
>   line 160, in streaming_bulk
>
> for result in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions,
>   raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, **kwargs):
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch-1.9.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/helpers/init.py",
>   line 132, in _process_bulk_chunk
>
> raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors),
>   errors)
>
> BulkIndexError: (u'2 document(s) failed to
>   index.',..document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True,
>   replicaset=u'mss'), u'local'), u'oplog.rs')
>
> 2016-02-29 19:56:59,835 [ERROR] mongo_connector.connector:302 -
>   MongoConnector: OplogThread unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down

---

Hi Val,

I connected with another mongodb instance, which had only one database, having one collection with 30,000+ records and I was able to execute it succesfully. The previous mongodb collection has multiple databases (around 7), which internally had multiple collections (around 5 to 15 per databases) and all were having good amount of documents (ranging from 500 to 50,000) in the collections.

Was Mongo-connector failing because of huge data residing in the mongo database ?

I have further queries

a. Is is possible to get indexing done of only specific collections in the mongodb, residing in different databases? I wan to index only specific collections (not the entire database). How can I achieve this ?

b. In elasticsearch i can see duplicate indexes for one collection. First one is with the database name (as expected), other one with the name mongodb_meta, both of them having same data, if I am changing the collection, the update is happening in both the collections.

c. Is it possible to configure the output index name or any other parameters any how?

Comment: Found answer to )

Reference: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/FAQ

What is the mongodb_meta index in Elasticsearch?

Mongo Connector creates a mongodb_meta index in Elasticsearch in order to keep track of when documents were last modified. This is used to resolve conflicts in the event of a replica set rollback event, but is kept in a separate index so that it can be removed easily if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only issue is that you have the `.py` extension on the doc manager (it was needed before mongo-connector 2.0), you simply need to remove it:

```
mongo-connector -m [remote mongo server IP]:[remote mongo server port] -t [elastic search server IP]:[elastic search server Port]  -d elastic_doc_manager
```

Comment: Bingo.. Thanks a lot again @val. Though, it is now throwing some other error now. I am looking into that now. :), Thank you so much.. !!!

Comment: What kind of error? Feel free to share as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found this option to run specific collection only.

$ mongo-connector -m mongodbserver:27017  -t elasticserver:9200 -d elastic_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt --namespace-set database.collection

Answer (score 0):

It started working after giving below command with --oplog-ts option.

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:37017 -d mongo_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt
```

But its failing if i use a config file. Kindly advise how to resolve this issue.

```
C:\Dev\mongodb\mongo-connector>mongo-connector -c myconfig.json --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt
Fatal Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\config.py", line 110, in parse_args
    self.load_json(f.read())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\config.py", line 132, in load_json
    parsed_config = json.loads(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 6 column 21 (char 201)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\util.py", line 90, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\connector.py", line 1059, in main
    conf.parse_args()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\config.py", line 112, in parse_args
    reraise(errors.InvalidConfiguration, *sys.exc_info()[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\compat.py", line 9, in reraise
    raise exctype(str(value)).with_traceback(trace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\config.py", line 110, in parse_args
    self.load_json(f.read())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\config.py", line 132, in load_json
    parsed_config = json.loads(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
mongo_connector.errors.InvalidConfiguration: Invalid \escape: line 6 column 21 (char 201)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
pip install 'elastic2-doc-manager[elastic5]'

mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager

Answer (score -1):

[answer on github](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/274)

> Your strategy seems sound to me. Here's how to do this:
>
> Generate a mongo-connector timestamp file:
>
> Run mongo-connector --no-dump.
>
> Stop mongo-connector right after it starts up. Now you have an
>   oplog.timestamp file pointing to the latest entry on the oplog.
>
> Run mongodump on the primary. The dump already reflects all the
>   changes that mongo-connector saw in the oplog.
>
> Run mongorestore with the dump from (2) on the target MongoDB.
>
> Restart mongo-connector. Pass in the file generated in (1) to the
>   --oplog-ts option.
>
> I'll add this to the wiki.